# Android: Loading Local Asset XML as URL

Tags: android, parsing, url

I'm playing around with a custom listview using this tutorial:

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

I'm running into an issue though with trying to modify it. If I want to use local android_assets instead of an XML file loaded from a web link, my app crashes. What I'm doing is changing this line:

```
 static final String URL = "http://api.androidhive.info/music/music.xml";
```

to this:

```
 static final String URL = "file:///android_asset/music.xml";
```

but when I do this, my app crashes on this line:

```
 String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
```

Any help would be awesome. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the xml file in your assets folder, try this out:

```
public String getStringFromAssets(Context ctx, String pathToFile)
{   
    InputStream rawInput;
    String text = "";

    try 
    {
        rawInput = ctx.getAssets().open(pathToFile);
        text = convertStreamToString(rawInput);

    } catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return text;  
}

String xml = getStringFromAssets(getApplicationContext(), "WhateverYourXmlFileNameIs");
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! Still couldn't quite get it to work, but I found another listview tutorial on creating my own list items in XML and pretty much did exactly what I wanted with just hard coding my items into the java activity instead of importing and parsing from an XML file.

Comment: Can you please give me the link of the tutorial you spoke of? I am also having the same issue!

Comment: what is convertStreamToString() ?